# Tableau scatter-plot: splitting measure using dimension from other data set

Tags: scatter-plot, tableau-api

I have a question on Tableau scatter-plots. Suppose I have two data sources, "data" and "meta". Data contains two columns, "variable" and "value" (as R melted data frame). Let's say variable ranges from a - d, and values 1 - 10. Meta classifies variables (columns: "variable", "class") so that a and b are "x", and c and d are "y". Tableau automatically links "variable" of data to "variable" of meta.

Now I would like to create a scatter-plot so that x's give x coordinates and y's give y coordinates. (And later split data further and add detail.) I thought this could be done dragging "value" to chart area and "class" to somewhere, but I cannot get it work.

One thing I've tried is to create a calculated field for x's and y's:

```
IF [meta].[class] == "x" THEN [value] END
```

This doesn't work, Tableau saying: "All fields must be aggregate or constant when using table calculation functions or fields from multiple data sources."

I feel I must be missing something obvious. I know I could create the scatter-plot reshaping the data, but it's not a good option in the case I have in mind.

Comment: Yup because Tableau is attempting to make the connection but from what it sounds like variable of data is not equal to variable of meta. They need to share a column in common in order for a relationship to be made.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Tableau is able to make the connection, as the columns "variable" contain same symbols. Reference to two different data sources in a calculated field seems to cause problems, but the example is so elementary that I'd suppose Tableau can easily handle it. But how?

Comment: What I'm saying is the Fields must be named exactly the same. This is indicated by NOT the gray hook but an orange hook.

Comment: For the above error you must have the linking field of the opposing connection somewhere on the worksheet. To make the relationship